# Object Adapter для Spinner

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

Есть ArrayList в котором находятся объекты класса Engineer (id, firstName, lastName).
Нужно создать выпадающий список, который отображает firstName и lastName. 
Класс Engineers:

```
public class Engineer {

    private int id;
    private String firstName, lastName;

    public Engineer(int id, String firstName, String lastName){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Адаптер пытаюсь делать так, но естественно выводит ссылку на объект класса.

```
ArrayAdapter adapterEngineers = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        adapterEngineers.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        engineer.setAdapter(adapterEngineers);
```

И ещё такой вопрос. Как получить значение элемента Spinner (firstName, lastName) указав id экземпляра класса?

Comment: так а какой 1 вопрос?

Comment: Как в Spinner выводить firstName и lastName объектов List?

Comment: В одном вопросе может быть только одна проблема. Если у вас несколько проблем - задайте несколько вопросов

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Engineer> {

    private Context context;
    private int mResource; // id вьюхи для свернутого списка
    private int dropDownResource; // id вьюхи для выпадающего списка
    private List<Engineer> engineers;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int mResource, int dropDownResource, List<Engineer> engineers) {
        super(context, mResource, engineers);
        this.context = context;
        this.mResource = mResource;
        this.dropDownResource = dropDownResource;
        this.engineers = engineers;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName).text = String.format(
                "%s %s",
                engineers.get(position).getFirstName(),
                engineers.get(position).getLastName()
        );
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(dropDownResource, parent, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName).text = String.format(
                "%s %s",
                engineers.get(position).getFirstName(),
                engineers.get(position).getLastName()
        );
        return view;
    }
}
```